# Can't find user tables MVC Web API

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5, claims-based-identity

After successful registration, can't find aspnet user tables and also when I tried to login, it returns invalid grant type

```
    public IdentityResult Register(string username, string password)
    {
        var userStore = new UserStore<IdentityUser>();
        var manager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(userStore);
        var user = new IdentityUser() { UserName = username, Email = username };
        manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
        {
            RequiredLength = 3
        };
        IdentityResult result = manager.Create(user, password);

        return result;

    }
```

when I tried to login, it returns invalid grant type

```
    public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        var userStore = new UserStore<IdentityUser>(new ApplicationDbContext());
        var manager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(userStore);
        var user = await manager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);

        if(user !=null)
        {
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("Username", user.UserName));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("Email", user.Email));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("LoggedOn", DateTime.Now.ToString()));

            context.Validated();
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
    }


public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("MyEntities")
    {
    }
    public DbSet<userlogindetails> userlogindetails{ get; set; }
}
```

webconfig

```
<add name="MyEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.MyModel.csdl|res://*/Models.MyModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.MyModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=MY-PC\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=MyDB;user id=user;password=pass;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that i need to add Default ConnectionString

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=My-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MyDB;User ID=username;Password=pass" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```